# query for checking the same value exist in both the tables ,how to combine the two query

Tags: mysql

Table 1

```
SELECT COALESCE(EMAIL, FB_EMAIL)as EMAILId  FROM o2core.t_o2_user_profile_details  where USER_ID=10011;
```

output of query 1 is

```
    EMAILId
bhanupriya@gmail.com
```

Table:2

```
SELECT CORP_USER_ID as  FROM o2core.t_o2_corp_user_reg_map as b where TH_ID=2 ;
```

output of query 2 is

```
    EMAILId
bhanupriya@gmail.com
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 AS emailIsUsedTwice
FROM t_o2_user_profile_details AS p
INNER JOIN t_o2_corp_user_reg_map AS m ON m.CORP_USER_ID = COALESCE(p.EMAIL, p.FB_EMAIL)
WHERE p.USER_ID = 10011;
```

It will be useful also to have an index on `t_o2_corp_user_reg_map.CORP_USER_ID`